# how to install wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.3.2 in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wkhtmltopdf

Now am using `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)`.
how can I upgrade this to the `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3.2`

am using **Ubuntu 14.04**